# Statement of Interest for Ph.D. admissions

Tags: statement-of-purpose

I am trying for a Ph.D. (computational biology) at IMSc, India ([link](https://www.imsc.res.in/graduate_programme_0)). They are asking a covering letter, a statement of interest, a curriculum vitae including university grades/marks. When I searched about statement of interest, some webpages were dealing this same as thesis proposal. So I am confused.

Is statement of interest, statement of purpose and thesis proposal same?

Comment: I think _statement of interest_ and _statement of purpose_ are the same. I am not sure about the thesis proposal. It seems to me that SoP/SoI is about yourself and the thesis proposal is about the thesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary difference between a *statement of interest (or purpose)* and a *thesis proposal* is the specificity. A thesis proposal outlines a specific project to be pursued during the thesis research, and will usually be written at some point during the process. However, in many cases, this is done *after* the graduate student has been accepted and joined a particular research group, rather than before admission has been granted. When asked for at the admission stage, it's usually in cases where the assignment to a particular research advisor is done at the outset of the doctoral program.

A statement of interest, on the other hand, simply details the kinds of problems or research areas a given student would like to pursue as a graduate student. This is usually asked for in admission cases where the decision is being made at the departmental level, rather than the individual faculty member level. A student is not specifically committing to a particular project at this stage—nor does the department necessarily want such a commitment.